# Current project location reference variable in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

In `application.properties`, I can use the `${user.home}` placeholder to refer to the home location of the current user.

In my case, I'm trying to refer to a file located in the `src/main/resources` folder. Is there a placeholder I can use to refer to this folder?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a property... but this sounds like you're trying to solve another problem which is not exactly what you're asking here (or this is a part of a bigger problem). If this is the case, could you share the specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @lealceldeiro I am trying to link the file which is located in my project(under src/main/resources, src/main/custom etc.)

Comment: Please, take a minute and try to [edit] your question in order to make it easier for use to help you as it is currently written is really hard to give you an answer.

Comment: you can access a resource in the __current project location__ by using __classpath:/the-resource-you-want__  more info here [boot-features-external-config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files located in `src/main/resources` are put onto the classpath. That means you could add a property like this:

```
my.prop=classpath:my-file.txt
```

If you bind this to a [`Resource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html), Spring will return the proper resource for you. For example:

```
 @Value("${my.prop}")
 private Resource myProp;
```

The `Resource` API has some useful methods if you plan on accessing this file, such as `getFile()`, `getInputStream()`, ... .

This approach also allows you to change the location of the file without having to change any code, for example:

```
my.prop=file:/path/to/my-file.txt
```

For more information you can check the [documentation about resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources).